# Jquery Ajax Error response not able to get form object in error block

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a generic function in jquery to handle forms. When get the response say 400 from my rest API, I am not able to access form object inside the error clause.

In following code e.target is the form object but can not access e in error clause, Even using global variable, (which is not good way) is not working

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                alert("Unexpected , contact admin");// handle the invalid form...
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: e.target.action,
                    method: e.target.method,
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 0) {
                            alert(' Check Your Network.');
                        }else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 404) {
                            alert('Requested URL not found.');
                        }else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 500) {
                            alert('Internel Server Error.');
                        }else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 400) {// Bad Request
                            $(e.target).append('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in alert-dismissable"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>')
                        }else {
                            alert('Unknow Error.\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }     
                    }
                });                 

                return false;
            }
        });
    })
```

The error I got in error block for $(e.tartget) , is e is not defined.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces issue

Answer (score 1):

I would not do it with the e.target ... check my code snippet, 
how would solve it.

Just get the current the from object via $(this)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
            
            //Get the target form 
            var form = $(this);
            
            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                alert("Unexpected , contact admin");// handle the invalid form...
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: e.target.action,
                    method: e.target.method,
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                    },
                    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                        if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 0) {
                            alert(' Check Your Network.');
                        }else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 404) {
                            alert('Requested URL not found.');
                        }else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 500) {
                            alert('Internel Server Error.');
                        }else if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 400) {// Bad Request                 
                            //Append the Error to the targeted form
                            form.append('<div class="alert alert-danger fade in alert-dismissable"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">×</a><strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action.</div>')
                        }else {
                            alert('Unknow Error.\n' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        }     
                    }
                });                 

                return false;
            }
        });
    })
```

Comment: Even I was able to get using e but getting few issues, but above code work like charm.. Thanks Only thing I corrected is I had to prepend :) This is real helpful. Thanks